# How to put array data from laravel to jquery array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a collection which is generated by `$user->roles` where `role` table has `role_name` and `permission` columns.

What i want is to get an array of permission and use it in `jquery` so i can use it in `select2` components which requires an array.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#role_select").select2();
          $('#role_select').val( {{ $user->roles->pluck('permission') }} ).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

above code doesnt work and in the console shows

```
[&quot;Super&quot;,&quot;Moderate&quot;]
```

So how can i get an array of permission by removing the `&quot;` ?

Comment: select2 plugin and jquery part of the question is irrelevant? the error is somewhere on the relations side in php...

Comment: All right, can you atleast var_dump  $user->roles()->permission so we can see how the data is structured?

Comment: @rand0m i have specified it in the question that the console shows the content of the select2 val as above

Comment: so, you have an array that reads ["Super","Moderate"] and you want that in your dropdown, is that it?

Comment: You shouldn't [mix JS and PHP](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes). Put the array into a hidden input or a JS variable instead. Or use a package to pass the data from Laravel to JS.

Comment: @Raj I think you need something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/zuqgu67g/

Comment: @rand0m thnx for your effort but i dont want to store it as option but give the array to the val function of select2 so that when the page loads the options are already selected. Leon already solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want your data escaped:

```
{!! $user->roles->pluck('permission') !!}
```

Comment: It works but Laravel doc says this "Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data." so is this safe ?

Comment: For your specific use case it is fine. You are not getting the role information from user input but via the laravel collection. ie. from the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 5):

Displaying Unescaped data is vulnerable to [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)), I suggest you to put your array in a html attribute like this:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="permissions" data-permissions="{{ json_encode($user->roles->pluck('permission')) }}"></div>
```

And then you can get the array of permissions by using [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
var permissions = $('#permissions').data('permissions');
```

Comment: thnx but as mentioned by Leon the data im displaying is from the database so there is no issue at all.

Comment: @Raj this is the right way to do that because you shouldn't mix PHP and JS as you did.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i have used @json() function of laravel. var permission =  @json($user->roles->pluck('permission'));